# How do i fill up the drawerLayout

Tags: android, material-design, drawerlayout

[image]

I designed my layout for `headerView` and wanted to add an image icon on its right side,just like the photo.

The problem is that it will show the spaces like in the image, even if I delete the image layout,the spaces are still there.

I try to change the parent layout or child layout for their layout width, any parameter like math parent or wrap content or give a dp.

I tried the official demo to fix it , but it did not work.

Can anyone teach me how to do this?

[image]
[image]

My nav_heafer.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#66CDAA"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!--the left navigationView-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
            <!--the left icon-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_grid_on_black_24dp" />
            <!--the left textView-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logIn"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pageLogIn"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <!--the left button-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/logOut"
                android:text="@string/logOut"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--I just want a outstanding icon over here,on the right side of navigationView-->
    <!--I try add the LinearLayout,but it shows strange-->
</LinearLayout>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQy1d.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9jyu.png
```

My MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context="com.example.user.taiwandigestionsociety_v11.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <!--control navigationView width-->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all right, finally i understood your problem and solved.This should give you something like below.
[image: navigation panel]

so let's get started!

very first of all you want to remove the white background behind your icon, so set transparent background  to your navigation view as shown below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    <!-- it works as transparent background color -->
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_support" />
```

for your custom header, you should use relative layout as parent because you want your close icon to be at the most right side of your navigation panel. so we can align that close icon according to parent. this time set background color to your direct child of your relative parent layout, as i did for linear layout.

In order to fit the icon within relative layout, leave some margin from right for linear layout, so leftovers right margin space will be occupied by your icon. set the same width of your icon as much space you pushed your linear layout from right. Here i leave 32dp margin from right, and set the width of my icon to match it.

For proper position of that icon i used the following attributes. You should adjust yours.

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

The nav_header.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="64dp"

            <!-- background color -->
            android:background="@color/blue_2"

            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_pin_primary"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_pin_primary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:typeface="normal"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- Other items go here -->
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/blue_2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pencil"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I change my nav_header.xml to match_parent, it' still there :(

Comment: thsnks @xFighter i reset the NavigationView width ,it succeed. I want to add the image just on the right side of the drawer now, it troubled me.

Comment: you want your image takes all the space remaining on the right side?

Comment: No , may be my title of the query is wrong. I just want to show the square image icon only on the right side of the drawer. The problem is there is a vertical line over there and remain a space.

Comment: i don't get it. can you please simplify it?

Comment: Ok hmm...My nav_heafer.xml has two vertical layout , one is for drawer and another is only for one image icon. 
When i show the drawer , i found it occupies a blank space. 
My problem is how to remove the blank space.

Comment: all right then, with support library you don't need do that menu and icon layout by your hands. There is a view called "Navigation View" that really works for menu and icons. take a look at it https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

Comment: and last thing is, if my answer helps you anyway then it should be take as an answer, shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry I know what you mean,BUT i want to use custom Navigation in my case,so i use only headerLayout not navigation menu.

Comment: I update my photo again,you misunderstanding me.This time i update the photo,take a look at that photo please.I really thanks for your help @xFighter,may the photo can let you know what issue bother me.

Comment: did you follow my this answer?

Comment: make your navigation's parent layout's width to match this  android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: Yes,i read your code,your point is orientation horizontal and layout weight.Do you mean this,right?
But i don't want to have an icon to right side of my text view,i want it out of the navigation header view.Just like the photo i pasted.

Comment: you now i see you can do with relative layout. Try it on your own with Relative Layout. hope this would help you.

Comment: hello once again, i solved your problem, you should better take a look at that

Comment: If i could , i should really invite you to have a cup of coffee @xFighter.

You solve my problem now , the original focus is the relative and it's margin right. , thank you very much really help these days.

Comment: Then we should be friend, shouldn't we? 

Answer (score 0):

all right this is not an answer to your question. But you can improve your layout as well as performance. Then change your nav layout in your question according to this and update your question once again. then it could be more readable and easy to understand your problems. so anybody could find it easy to answer

Instead using a linear layout with orientation horizontal for icon and textView you can do instead as i shown below.

> You current Implementation:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_grid_on_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newInformation"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/newInformation"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

> Now change that to something like this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/person_address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <!-- this is where your icon goes -->
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_grid_on_black_24dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_grid_on_black_24dp"

    <!-- your icon's padding -->
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

please change your layout into something like this, then i could try to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiasm and sorry too slow too respond,so you want me to paste yout textView to replace of the image(id:imageView9) and textView and linearlayout right ?
I change it,but it just crash and no any error information. What's should i to do ?

Comment: i think you can't get me right. you don't need linearLayout and ImageView to show them next to one another. you can simply use the approach i showed in my example.

Comment: i really don't get it,so you mean i don't need to use two linearlayout right?
Just use one imageIcon controll it by padding in one layout,it will shows what i want,a navigation view hava a icon on the right side of it.
Is that so ?

Comment: now i don't get you... we might need other speaking language... :(

Comment: Now i can understand what you mean,i have updated my question.
Can be more easily understood?